# Добавление элемента в simpeCursorAdaper

Tags: android, java

Имеется `ListView` и `SimpleCursorAdaper`. отображаю в списке только одно поле - `MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE`. но мне понадобилось сделать так, чтобы первый пункт этого списка мог добавиться не из курсора, а вручну. гугление подсказало, что можно использовать класс `MatrixCursor` а затем объединить их в объекте `MergeCursor`

```
MatrixCursor extras = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id", "title" });
extras.addRow(new String[] { "-1", "New Template" });
extras.addRow(new String[] { "-2", "Empty Template" });
Cursor[] cursors = { extras, cursor };
Cursor extendedCursor = new MergeCursor(cursors).
```

К сожалению не помогло. Первый элемент вставился, но остальные начали отображать себя не как прежде. т.е. до объединения курсоров, я отображал колонку TITLE, а после начала отображаться колонка DATA

Comment: в общем решил проблему примерно так:
добавлял в дополнительный курсор массив не с двумя полями, а с теми, которые присутствуют в MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.
MatrixCursor m = new MatrixCursor(c.getColumnNames());
получился к сожалению быдло-код, но как временное решение, сгодится.